# Hibernate Tools - Not able to add configuration - dom4j connection Timedout -

Tags: java, hibernate, dtd, hibernate.cfg.xml, dtd-parsing, xml

I created a small project in my company today. In Hibernate Perspective I try to add new configuration so that I can create entities easily from db tables which have several columns. But when I select my project, it gives me `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml`

Complete Stack Trace -

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.proxy.ConfigurationProxy.configure(ConfigurationProxy.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.loadConfigurationXML(ConfigurationFactory.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.configureStandardConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.buildConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension$5.execute(HibernateExtension.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.execute(HibernateExtension.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.buildWith(HibernateExtension.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.build(HibernateExtension.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.build(ConsoleConfiguration.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect Nested exception: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
    ... 18 more
```

Even after using many hibernate versions and changing DTD many times I am not able to figure out the issue. Can someone please help me on this. It is a simple maven project and .cfg.xml file is placed into src/main/java

I even downloaded a simple project from this url http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/ and then tried to add new configuration but again got the same problem. I just changed the respective DB credentials I had. They are correct since using the same jdbc url I have created a new DB connection in Data Source Explorer successfully. 
Kindly help.

Internet is working fine in my company.

Comment: Did you tried the suggestions from this thread: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2245020

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the DTD definition in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` from:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

to:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

This way the XML parser will not attempt to load the DTD file from the Internet, but it will try to load it from the Hibernate jars.

Comment: No it gives same error Classpath]: Could not parse configuration:C:\Workspaces\excelws\HibernateExample\src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml
When core is selected. 
And [Classpath]: Could not load AnnotationConfiguration when Annotations is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the config file throw web browser(firefox)， to check whether your config file is OK. If it has some thing wrong, the browser will show it out to you.
I refer to (http://blog.csdn.net/caixiexin/article/details/7024623).